# How to make multiple selects in html with jquery .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<center>
    <h3> A </h3>
    <h4> vs </h4>
    <h3> B </h3>
    <h4> 60 - 70 </h4>
</center>

<div class="12u$">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select name="teamA" id="A" style="max-width:30%;">
            <option value="">- TeamA -</option>
            <option value="1">Kansas</option>
            <option value="1">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="1">Texas</option>
            <option value="1">Notre Dame</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="12u$">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select name="teamB" id="B" style="max-width:30%;">
            <option value="">- TeamB -</option>
            <option value="1">Kansas</option>
            <option value="1">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="1">Texas</option>
            <option value="1">Notre Dame</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("select")
        .change(function() {
            var str = "Team A";
            $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                str = $(this).text() + " ";
            });
            $("h3").text(str);
        })
        .change();
</script>
```

This will work for one selector but how do I make another script that changes a separate select.

Comment: What do you mean by changes a separate select??

Comment: You have an extra `<` in your code before the `<script>` tag

Comment: So I have two selects and I want them to change two different texts, however this script can only point to one select currently. I have made another select and how to do I change the script so I can change them independently?

Comment: So based on the value of the option selected in the first dropdown, you want to change the value of the second dropdown to something?

Comment: The last `.change()` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Can you put the code for both dropdowns in your question?  Or a jsfiddle.net would be better.

Comment: You need to add the proper Mark up with your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xv1ozszv/

Comment: OK, thanks for the fiddle.  Now when they select Team A, what do you want to happen?  Team B?

Comment: updated: https://jsfiddle.net/xv1ozszv/  I want the selectors to be able to change the h3's independently

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ID of your selects, (btw, id A and B are a bit.. short..)

```
$("#A").change();
$("#B").change();
```

Or check what ID the select has:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    if(this.id == "A")
    {
        // Its the first one that changed
    }
    else if(this.id == "B")
    {
        // Its the second one that changed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the headers have id's that correspond to the select's id, you can use the select's id to obtain the corresponding headers. e.g. with header ids 'hA' and 'hB':

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    $('#h' + this.id).text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv1ozszv/1/)